# Is it possible because of low RAM the MotherBoard getting effected?

Tags: memory, motherboard

Is it possible to have Low RAM in the System and because of this the MotherBoard getting problem.Actually I have Apple MacMini with Lion OS and 2GB of RAM.when I Install Titanium with Android SDK and Run Android Simulator My OS Getting Crashed.My Hardisk capacity is 500GB and I have used 50GB among them.I don't know the reason why this happen?

Comment: define "problems". If the system has less than a supported amount of RAM (is that even possible?) that could be it, otherwise I thought the OS would just run really really slow. How much RAM have you got in it?

Comment: Are you confusing [hard drive disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive) space with [computer memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_memory) space? Have you looked into the [Mac OS X Task Manager](http://osxdaily.com/2010/08/15/mac-task-manager/) to identify whether there is high usage of any of the resources? Make sure to check out the different tabs for the Disk Usage too. Please add this information to your question by clicking the [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/370162/edit) link, such that we better understand what is happening. Did it freeze or kernel panic?

Comment: Actually I have got kernel panic 2 to 3 times but most of time it is freezed.

Comment: Having not enough RAM is very unlikely to cause a kernel panic. Having *bad* RAM, on the other hand, is very likely to do so.

Comment: @AnkitVyas: Welcome to Super User! Can you also specify the memory conditions, as in how many RAM is being used and what your CPU is at? You can see those in the [Task Manager](http://osxdaily.com/2010/08/15/mac-task-manager/). Did the accepted answer really help you solve the problem? Or did you accidentally accept it? Accepting means that "this is the solution that I can use to completely solve the problem".

Comment: Actually When this happen i was stuck with the system.I was not able to do anything.I had only one way that was Restart.so I thought in Mac Crash may be the reason for low memory.Now I have given the system to the Apple store they have given me the reason that your Logic board getting problem so now i came to know that some kind of application required sufficient memory for working properly.Thanks for the supporting me and i hope i have got this kind of support again.Thank you once again to all of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your initial question, there is no chance **whatsoever** for your motherboard to develop a problem because of too little RAM.

As to rest of your problem, the crash could theoretically be due to low RAM (though not that likely).

If you can, please provide some info on what tasks are running concurrently and also look at the logs from when the kernel panic occurred (see http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2546 for info on where they are located). We may be able to help track it down.

Comment: I doubt if that's correct. In the case of Windows, applications are closed when the RAM is low in a manner that doesn't result in BSODs. I would take the assumption that Mac OS X (or even any *nix based system) implements a similar behavior to handle low memory conditions. Inspecting the kernel panics is none-the-less a good idea, although the problem could be anything if he doesn't give further resource specifications. Memory leaks on the other hand, are able to result in kernel panics and freezes...